# How to properly configure Entity Framework Core and SQL Server Charset / Encoding?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, encoding, entity-framework-core, collation

My application is using EF Core 6.0.5 and connecting to SQL Server Database. I'm facing an issue with a specific character in the database that can't be read correctly.

When the application reads the character **Ó** it is transformed in the encoding **A\u0093**. Other special characters like **ã** and **ç** are correct, what seems odd.

The Database Collation is: **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**

The column data type is: **nvarchar()**

The system System.Text.Encoding Default property is: **System.Text.UTF8Encoding+UTF8EncodingSealed**

Comment: If you are using UTF8 you need to use a UTF8 collation and a `varchar`, not `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and an `nvarchar`. `nvarchar` doesn't use UTF8 it uses UCS-2. You should find that encoding your characters in UTF16 works (unless you have some characters that use surrogate pairs, where you'll want to then use a collation that supports them).

Comment: @Larnu should I change the collation to Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 and the column type to varchar? Did I get it correctly?

Comment: I would change your application to use UTF16, to be honest.